# How to add strings to an array inside a php function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have this function that doesn't work.
**$b** is an outside string that should bond with $a array that should return a group of strings.

```
$a=array('this','is');
function chkEdt($a,$b) {
 $a[]=$b;
};
print_r($a);
```

Result -> array();

Why?

Comment: If you want the function to change the value of a parameter that's been passed to it, you need to [pass by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it a reference parameter.

```
function chkEdt(&$a,$b) {
    $a[]=$b;
};
```

Then any changes to `$a` in the function will affect the array variable that's used as the argument.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I'll study reference parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your example never actually calls the chkEdt function, and that function never returns anything.

Aside from that, variables have different scope inside and outside functions - even though they share a name, they are considered to be different variables because one of them is inside a function. Read https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more detail.

You can either pass the variable by reference as in [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016889/5947043), or you can make the function return a value and then re-assign the `$a` outside the function to the value returned by the function - like this:

```
$a = array('this','is');

function chkEdt($a,$b) {
 $a[] = $b;
 return $a;
};

$a = chkEdt($a, "a");
print_r($a);
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00d19028b3909ca415b81e93c26a6ede9188c743

To clarify the difference, you could re-write the function with a different variable name within the function, and get the same result:

```
$a = array('this','is');

function chkEdt($z,$b) {
 $z[] = $b;
 return $z;
};

$a = chkEdt($a, "a");
print_r($a);
```